# preg_replace() array remove specific string that contains white spaces

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, space

I try to match this specific string **" et "** that contains both whitespaces on each side of the "et" word.

In this simplified code:

```
$in = "Retour et échange"
$search = array(" et ");
$replace = array("");
$return = preg_replace($search, $replace, $in);
```

I tried all of these options:

```
"[ et ]"
"[\set\s]"
"[\s(et)\s]"
" et "
"\set\s"
"\s(et)\s"
"\s[et]\s"
```

None of them is working!

I would like to have this result:

**"Retour échange"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$search` array must be an array of patterns, not an array of strings, add delimiters:

```
$search = array("/ et /");
//        here __^  __^
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preg_replace() you could use str_replace(). 
`$in = "Retour et échange";
$search = " et ";
$replace = " ";
$return = str_replace($search, $replace, $in);`

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the ridiculous problem. I was already removing single whitespace in another array value.

These are working well

```
"/ et /"
"[ et ]"
```

Thank you everybody!

Comment: That's exactly what I said. It will be nice to accept my answer.